# How to add attributes from external JSON to a FlowFile

Tags: apache-nifi

Need help folks.

I have two files that should be parsed together into a single flowfile:

1. A csv file that should be the flowfile content.
2. A JSON file that should be the flowfile attributes.

How can I do it in NiFi without resorting to a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The logic would be :**

1 - GetFile (You Read the Json)

2 - Get Attributes from Json

3 - Set filename attribute to your csv file

4 - Fetch csv file (goes straight to the flow content)

**Your flow should look like this :**
[image]

I have create a sample template for this use case:

http://www.aodba.com/apache-nifi-template-integrate-multiple-files-single-flow-2/

Comment: That's perferct. Thank you!

Comment: Seem problems ! :)